# pure CSS to hover over a div hide the content and then display new text

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to display some content in a div column element (an icon and some title text).  When I hover over the text, I am trying to hide the content by transitioning a box over the old content then display more information on top of the new coloring

I am currently using the :before psuedo element to transition a new background color which is initially 0 opacity then transitioning up and to full opacity.  I can not seem to get my child div to then show on top.

```css
.feature {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feature h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #006699;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.feature a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.feature .icon {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #575757;
}

.feature:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #003366;
  transition: all 0.33s ease;
  z-index: 10;
}

.feature .details {
  display: none;
  z-index: 15;
}

.feature:hover:before {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(75, 179, 219, 0.75);
  z-index: 10;
}

.features:hover .details {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature h_medium bg-gray radius-2">
  <div class="icon mb-15">
    <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>
  </div>
  <h2>Main Title</h2>
  <div class="details">
    <h2>Main Title (again)</h2>
    <p>Some level of content that describes the title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Id expect the hover to first populate the blue box cover over the feature element -- then I would expect the details div to populate over the blue box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's my solution for you. Hope it will meet up your requirements. I just made some changes in following blocks. Feel free to inform if you face any problem.

```
.feature .details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}

.feature:hover .details {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.33s ease .2s;
}
```

```css
.feature {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feature h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #006699;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.feature a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.feature .icon {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #575757;
}

.feature:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background-color: #003366;
    transition: all 0.33s ease;
    z-index: 10;
}

.feature .details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}

.feature:hover:before {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(75,179,219,0.75);
    z-index: 10;
}

.feature:hover .details {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.33s ease .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature h_medium bg-gray radius-2">
        <div class="icon mb-15">
            <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Main Title</h2>
        <div class="details">
            <h2>Main Title (again)</h2>
            <p>Some level of content that describes the title</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```